# Именование таблиц SQL в подзапросе

Tags: sql, oracle

Если мы повторно обращаемся к таблице из основного запроса, рассматриваем мы её "с нуля" или в усеченном условиями варианте из основного вопроса. Например:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IDX1.<столбец_1>
  FROM <таблица_1> IDX1
 INNER JOIN <таблица_2> IDX2 
    ON IDX1.<столбец_n> = IDX2.<столбец_m>
   AND IDX2.<столбец_1> IN (<список>)
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT <таблица_1>.*
         FROM <таблица_1> IDX1
        WHERE <условия>)
```

Так вот, обращаясь к `<таблице_1>` в подзапросе, имеем ли мы дело с полной таблицей, или усеченной условием, наложенным при присоединении `<таблицы_2>`?

Comment: В общем виде сказать ничего нельзя. оптимизатор может преобразовать not exists например в not in или в left join. И выполнить его вообще всего один раз, если он не коррелированный. Т.е. никто не сказал, что оптимизатор будет делать так, как тут написано. он вполне может сначала выполнить подзапрос, а потом выбрать подходящее из таблиц в верху. А может и наоборот, скачала выполнить все условия в ON (или только часть из них и работать пока с одной таблицей) и потом для результатов выполнят подзапрос. Так что ответ один - смотрите explain plan для конкретной ситуации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При обращении к таблице в подзапросе сработают только те условия, которые в этом подзапросе написаны.

Справедливости ради надо заметить, что в подзапросе можно можно обращаться к таблицам более высокого уровня и тогда у них могут появляться общие условия. Например:

```
Select * 
from   Table1 t1
where  exists (select 1 from Table1 t2 where t1.col1 = t2.col2)
```

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае если целью является оптимизация, то можно воспользоваться `WITH ... CLAUSE` и хинтом `MATERIALIZE`:

```
with view_name as
  ( select /*+ materialize */ from table_name where ... )
select
...
from view_name v1
where col_name not in (select col_name from view_name);
```

в вашем случае стоит попробовать вариант с разностью множеств и сравнить планы выполнения:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IDX1.col1
FROM (
    SELECT col1
    FROM tab1
    MINUS
    SELECT col1 FROM tab1 WHERE ...
) as IDX1
JOIN tab2 IDX2
  ON IDX1.<столбец_n> = IDX2.<столбец_m> AND IDX2.<столбец_1> IN (<список>)'
```

Comment: Стоит отметить, что `materialize` недокументированный хинт, и его использование не рекомендуется